# how use html and jsp pages in spring boot web application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using spring boot web application with maven.
**My issue is that when I am using jsp or html page as a view it display page not found error** but there is no error in my code

> here is the code that I am use for configure the view resolver and controller
>   **code in my controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/temp")
public String temp(){
    return "temp";
}
```

> temp is my html page which is located in WEB-INF/html folder

**code in my config class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("fileuploadtest")
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/html/", ".html");
}
}
```

> **and the error that was show is**

**o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/html/temp.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'**

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: I am already using war packaging not jar

Comment: is this is the problem of intellij idea because jsp run in netbeans perfectly

Comment: and I want to use html also

Answer (score 3):

In application.properties file use this code, make sure you are using **thymeleaf**:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.thymeleaf.view-names:thymeleaf/*
```

And to call a HTML, use this code:

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String getIndex() {
        return "thymeleaf/index";
    }
```

And to call a JSP page, use this code:

```
@GetMapping("/form")
    public String getform2() {
        logger.info("ttesting form.jsddp");
        return "form";
    }
```

Your project structure will look something like this:

[image: link to project structure]

Now run this project on a server like Tomcat and it will work fine.

Comment: really really excellent answer. i wish see more like this. +1